# Beamer: Removing the extra circle on the "Thank you" page brought by the outertheme "smoothbars"

Tags: beamer

When using beamer's outer theme `smoothbars`, I tried to exclude the "Thank you" page from the circles by adding an `\appendix`. However, this causes an extra circle on the upper right corner of the frame. Is there any way to remove this extra circle?

Below is an MWE. As you can see, there is an extra circle on the upper right corner.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        Thank you!
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code found in [how-to-configure-final-frame-in-latex-beamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190431/how-to-configure-final-frame-in-latex-beamer) to turn off the miniframes.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

%%*************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190431/how-to-configure-final-frame-in-latex-beamer
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
    \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
    {\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}
}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother
%%***************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \section{First}
    \begin{frame}
        Some text
    \end{frame}
    
    \appendix
    \miniframesoff % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{center}
            Thank you!
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```